# Reading File Line by Line and storing into an Multidimensional Array or ArrayList

Tags: java, loops

I have a file that contains information from different tweets separated by a \t. The information contains the fields user, language, and text.

What I need to do is store the information about the tweet in an ArrayList or an array, such that each word is separated, so that I can iterate through them and compare them.

Here is an example of the file

```
@GracieWhitton  en  RT @GracieWhitton: I need 16 more followers to 2500. I know      you are out there!! Come on folks. :)
@SHARPErThnYu   en  RT @SHARPErThnYu: Stop texting me. Our relationship is non existent
@BraandiiSongz  fr  RT @BraandiiSongz: Le 1er rdv chui tj timide ac une grosse boule au ventre apr c autre chose
@BeyTomce   en  @BeyTomce Saturday ???
@VivoPorVoceLuaB    pt  @VivoPorVoceLuaB Segui,Sdv amore
@JamelTaylour   en  "@str8BappN: @JamelTaylour That go bruh"right on bro
@eluniweb   es  RT @eluniweb: #UCAB maÃ±ana martes 16 de abril hay clases  http://t.co/ZeUzGBM7MI
@MariAleAguirre es  RT @MariAleAguirre: Que CINISMO el de El Ciudadano en GLOBOTERROR. Esta diciendo que VTV fue el que llamo a la violencia en Altamira...  ...
```

Here is my code, and I don't know why it doesen't work as I want. I don't know how to iterate over the data.

```
public Tweets() throws FileNotFoundException {

    Scanner in=new Scanner(new File("./twitter/data.txt"));
    ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> comments= new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();

    while(in.hasNext()){
        String line=in.nextLine();
        String[] data=line.split("\t",-1);

        ArrayList<String> words = new ArrayList<String>();
        words.add(data[0]);
        words.add(data[1]);
        String[] w=data[2].split(" ",-1);

        for(int i=0;i<w.length-1;i++)
        {
            words.add(w[i]);
        }

        comments.add(words);

    }
    in.close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need [Scanner#hasNextLine](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#hasNextLine%28%29)

```
while(in.hasNextLine()){
```

Also check for the delim `"\t"`

Comment: try `String[] data=line.split("\\t",-1);`

Answer (score 0):

Finally I did it. I used an ArrayList of an ArrayList

I'll leave here the way I resolved it. Maybe its useful for someone.

```
    public Tweets() throws Exception {


    Scanner in=new Scanner(new File("./twitter/data.txt"));
    ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> comments= new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
    ArrayList<String> words = new ArrayList<String>();
    String[] line;
    String str;
    String [] tweet;
    while(in.hasNextLine())
    {
        str=in.nextLine();
        line = str.split("\t");
        tweet = line[2].split(" ");
        for(String word : tweet)
            words.add(word);
    }
    comments.add(words);
    // Printing the content of words
    for(ArrayList<String> tt : comments)
        for(String word : tt)
            System.out.println(word);
}
```